# Azure Data Factory v2 not displayed in Server Explorer or Cloud Explorer in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-data-factory

I have a data factory (version 2) and a bunch of other resources in my Azure subscription, and have logged into that subscription using Visual Studio 2015. When I open the Server Explorer or Cloud Explorer, I can see most of my resources (ie SQL Servers & Databases, Data Lakes, Logic Apps, and Streaming Jobs), but my data factory is not shown in either. Is data factory not supported by this view, or is there a way I can fix this?

I believe I have everything up to date, and am currently using Windows 10 version 1803. I've looked through SO and MSDN and can't find anything on not seeing data factories specifically.

**Installed Products:**

- Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 (version 14.0.25431.01)
- Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0 (version 14.0.30823.0)
- Common Azure Tools (version 1.8)
- DataFactoryProject (version 1.0)
- Microsoft Azure Data Factory Node Node (version 1.0)
- Microsoft Azure Tools (version 2.9)

Comment: Is your Azure Data Factory version1 or version2? version2 doesn't show up in Server and Cloud explorer - and I think that's by design.

Comment: @databash we are using v2. Do you know of any documentation supporting that?

Answer (score 0):

As same as you, azure Data Factory V2 doesn't show up in `Cloud Explorer` in both of version 2015 and version 2017.

Based on this [document](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.CloudExplorerForVS#overview), the tool only supports for subscritptions by resources that have Role Based Access Control (RBAC) applied as well as those in Cloud Solution Providers (CSP) and DreamSpark programs.

You could write a review [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.CloudExplorerForVS#review-details) to find the facts.

Comment: I appreciate the reply, but Data Factory v2 supports RBAC, and we have it active on the resource - from the documentation shown, DF v2 should work with Cloud Explorer.

Comment: @chazbot7 Sure I know, so maybe you could commit feedback in the document to find the facts.